# css, border over border

Tags: html, css

I have this design of a table with a menu next to it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/24/), The problem is that the corners of the `#settingNev ul li a` is shown on the `border-right` so there are little white dots and the border the is connected to the menue and the table(you can se the in the fiddle easly).

How can i do hat they wont be? i want that the `ul`'s `li` `background-color` will stay white and will not transparent(transparent solves it)?

Also i dont want to set the left,top and bottom borders as 0px becaus ethen when its hover one `li` the other move

Comment: Umm, you shouldn't capitalize stuff in css

Comment: Why don't you try changing the background color instead on hover? That would be much easier.

Comment: change the background? can you give an example in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar to musefans answer but with a fix^^

```
#settingNev ul li a {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
    color: #666;
    //padding: 5px 3px;
    padding: 6px 3px 6px 4px;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    //margin: 1px 0 1px 1px;
}
#settingNev ul li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    //margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 3px;
}
#settingNev .active a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    //margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 3px;
}
```

[here is a fiddle(updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/LFd75/1/)

also you have some duplicated css in you fidle

UPDATE: use padding instead of margin this works now you can see it in my updated fiddle

Comment: ohh thanks didnt see that, and the <li>s still move when hover